# Who gave Nuala her pendant?

Tags: vertigo-comics, the-sandman

This pendant was given to Nuala by some woman Morpheus has courted.

[image]

Yet which one? It was the latest one, surely, after Morpheus admitted Nuala to his palace. My best guess is that it was Thessaly (aka Larissa), but I wasn't able to locate any proof.

Comment: It was Thessaly, but I'm fuzzy on the actual dialog.  It's referenced in both *Kindly Ones* (when she's guarding Lyta Hall and preventing Morpheus from disturbing her channeling of the Furies) and *The Wake* (where she actually cries), but I'm not sure which piece of dialogue makes the relationship explicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's Thessaly. As Radhil says in the comments, we know from various clues that Thessaly is the girlfriend they're talking about. In *A Game of You*, Morpheus and Thessaly meet, and Thessaly shows some interest (although she seems more annoyed: "He comes on like he's so cool. Who does he think he's fooling. Well, he's not fooling me. Oh no . . . and it isn't even as if he's good-looking. He's too thin for a start."). And then she tells the story about the relationship and breakup in *The Wake*.

But there's a particular link with the pendant. At the end of *World's End* (Sandman volume 8), Brant is telling his story to a bartender who looks like Thessaly, and she seems to be wearing the pendant.

[image: World's End bartender 1]
[image: World's End bartender 2]

Comment: I never doubted that it was Thessaly (after her part in *The Kindly Ones* and *The Wake*), I just wanted proof. Thank you very much for your research! I'll wait for a day and then accept.

Comment: I might have learned about the pendant from one of the Sandman companion books. There's also some more detail about the Dream/Thessaly relationship on this oocities page: http://www.oocities.org/fynwong/thessaly.html.